# Select the max timestamp in hive

Tags: hive, conditional-statements, max, datetime-format

[image]

I have a table-customer with two records in the different timestamp. I want to select the max timestamp records: 2014-08-15 15:54:07.379.

```
Select Customer_ID, Account_ID, max(ProcessTimeStamp)
from Customer
group by Customer_ID,   Account_ID
```

I should get one record, but the actual result is two records.

How can I get the max ProcessTimeStamp records?

Comment: You are grouping by Account_ID that has different values, therefore the result is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use windows function here.
Either you can use dense_rank() or row_num().

1.USING DENSE_RANK()

```
select customer_id,account_id,processTimeStamp
    from (select *
          ,dense_rank() over(partition by customer_id order by processTimeStamp desc) as rank
          from "your table" 
         ) temp
    where rank=1
```

2.USING ROW NUMBER

```
select customer_id,account_id,processTimeStamp
        from (select *
              ,row_number() over(partition by customer_id order by processTimeStamp desc) as rank
              from "your table" 
             ) temp
        where rank=1
```

BUT with row_number() each row will get a unique number and if there are duplicate records than row_number will give only the row where row number=1(in above mentioned case).

Comment: Hi Vishal, I will verify your solution and go back to you when I am done. Thanks!